# Cheaply modifiable datastructure for complex data in C++

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I started to work on a private project where I'm collecting, sorting, and changing data from a website. Initially, I thought `QVariantMap` will serve the purpose and passing the container as a reference between the different functions will not cause an overhead, but `QVariantMap` content can't be accessed and modified as a reference, so whenever I want to amend data in the container I have to copy the whole data structure which is not optimal.

What do you suggest doing? Is a local database a good solution for this use case?

Comment: Where do you get the notion that the content of a `QMap<Key, T>` cannot be accessed and modified by reference? `QMap<Key, T>::find()` returns a `QMap<Key, T>::iterator` object with accessor method `T& QMap<Key, T>::iterator::value()`. There you have your writable reference to the content.

Comment: Note that if you want all your components to work on the same container and avoid the Copy-On-Write paradigm of Qt, you can simply use a `std::unordered_map<Key, QVariant>` instead.

Comment: a local database is almost never a good solution